# Find() method of an std::string pointer

Tags: c++

I have a function like this:

```
int find_string ( string *url){
   if(*url.find() != string::npos){
        [...]
   }
   [...]
}
```

And call it this way:

```
find_string(&url);
```

But I got the following compiling error:

```
request for member ‘find’ in ‘url’, which is of non-class type ‘std::string*’
```

Why this happen and, most importantly, how can I fix this? (When there was no pointer, it was working)

Comment: This is called operator precedence, have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence. `*` has a lower precedence than `.`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*url.find()` is equivalent to `*(url.find())` when what you actually want is `(*url).find()`. Better yet you should be using `url->find()` instead.

The reason for this is the dereference (`*`) operator has lower [precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than the element selection (`.`) operator.

Answer (score 3):

use `(*url).find()` or, better `url->find()`

`*url.find` tries call `find()` function and then use `operator *`